# How to serve a Flutter Web SPA with Fermyon Spin

Tags: flutter, dart, single-page-application, fermyon-spin

I'm trying to serve a [Flutter Web](https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/web) SPA with [Fermyon Spin](https://www.fermyon.com/spin)
below are the steps I followed (besides flutter and fermyon installation)

#### steps to reproduce

1. create a static file server with fermyon
   `spin new static-fileserver fermyon_flutter_test`
2. open folder and create a flutter web application
   `cd fermyon_flutter_test && flutter create fermyon_flutter_test --platforms web`
3. open folder and build flutter for web
   `cd fermyon_flutter_test && flutter build web --release`
4. back to "spin" folder and modify "files" in `spin.toml`\

- `cd ..`

```
-- files = [{ source = "assets", destination = "/" }]
++ files = [{ source = "fermyon_flutter_test/build/web/", destination = "/" }]
```

5. run spin server and open in browser

- `spin up`
- `open http://127.0.0.1:3000/static`

#### expected result

[flutter counter app](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1) is shown in the browser

#### actual result

http://127.0.0.1:3000/static (or http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/index.html for the matter)
shows a white page

#### logs

```
Serving http://127.0.0.1:3000
2023-10-03T15:04:56.295117Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Serving http://127.0.0.1:3000
Available Routes:
  fermyon_flutter_test: http://127.0.0.1:3000/static (wildcard)
2023-10-03T15:05:01.712096Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/
2023-10-03T15:05:06.503163Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/static
2023-10-03T15:05:06.503235Z TRACE spin_trigger_http::spin: Executing request using the Spin executor for component fermyon_flutter_test
2023-10-03T15:05:06.508941Z  INFO spin_trigger_http::spin: Request finished, sending response with status code 200 OK
2023-10-03T15:05:06.520199Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/flutter.js
2023-10-03T15:05:06.636799Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.png
2023-10-03T15:05:06.652413Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/manifest.json
2023-10-03T15:05:44.002289Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/flutter.js
2023-10-03T15:05:44.112978Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.png
2023-10-03T15:05:44.128424Z  INFO spin_trigger_http: Processing request for application fermyon_flutter_test on URI http://127.0.0.1:3000/manifest.json
```

#### info

`spin 1.5.1 (8d4334e 2023-09-26)`

```
Flutter 3.13.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ead455963c (7 days ago) • 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
Engine • revision a794cf2681
Tools • Dart 3.1.3 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

Comment: Is there an index.html in the 'fermyon_flutter_test/build/web/' folder? "If an index.html file is in the source root, it will be served if no file is specified."

Comment: yes there is, but it is not served

Comment: Did you add `--base-href=/static/` to your `flutter build web` to tell it that it will be served from a 'subdirectory' rather than the root?

Comment: What does the browser's dev tool network tab show? Presumably a bunch of 404s as it tries to fetch URLs like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/manifest.json` (Note - should presumably be `http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/manifest.json` If you try to manual fetch the former do you get 404 and 200 for the latter?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Flutter Web expects the script to be served, but if you change you Spin file server route to be `/...` (the root of your endpoint), then your application should work. (Just tested with the Flutter Web template right now) -- `route = "/..."`

If you want to serve from `/static`, then @RichardHeap's comment is the way to go here (and you should set `route=/static/...` in your `spin.toml`).

Comment: @radu-matei
 your answer is correct! if your write it as an answer I'll accept it asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution suggested by [radu-matei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3084239/radu-matei) in the comments above fixes the issue
just set in `spin.toml` file

```ini
route = "/..."
```